# Python- How to convert a string to float ( i know what float() function is my question is different)

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have a problem converting string to float. For example, I want to get an input like `10**2` and I want the program to save the result of `10**2` in the variable.

like this :

```py
Number = float(input("Enter the number : "))
print(number * 2)
```

something like this and when i run and it says :

```
Enter the number :
```

and I give it `10**2` I want it to return `200`

like this :

```
Enter the number : 10**2
200
```

How can I do it? I tried different ways non worked.

Comment: `10**2` is `100`, not `200`.

Comment: Ok, I can see your code and what you expect, but what does your code do and why is it not right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` to parse general arithmetic expressions:

```
Number = eval(input("Enter the number : "))
print(Number * 2)
```

You can even provide formulas, such as `10**2 + 5`, etc.

Comment: might be worth a warning! a silly/naughty user could enter `__import__('os').system('rm /')` which might not be bad, but adding "-rf" in there probably would be

Comment: I guess that is concern if this is plugged into a website, but the use case of the OP seemed to be an everyday application. In that case, `eval` is the same as the user opening a terminal and typing commands.

Answer (score -1):

Change "number" to Number", and format the print as follows:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat readIn.py
Number = float(input("Enter the number : "))
print("%.0f\n" % (Number * 2))
Mac_3.2.57$python readIn.py
Enter the number : 10**2
200

Mac_3.2.57$
```